# Dual Booting Ubuntu 17.04 and Windows 10 NTFS partition marked as bitlocker

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, mount, windows-10, ntfs

I have a Thinkpad laptop with Windows 10 and a 1 TB drive.  I have repartitioned the drive to have a 150GB Windows c drive; a 90GB EXT4 partition with ubuntu 17.04 on it and a 700GB NTFS partition for data to be accessed by both OSes. 
Dual boot works absolutely fine but I don't seem to be able to mount the 700GB partition.  Gparted shows it as filesystem bitlocker.  from windows it is shown as bitlocker not enabled and the partition is not encrypted.  I dont need bitlocker.
fdisk identifies the partition as:

/dev/nvme0n1p4  309133312 1814038527 1504905216 717.6G Microsoft basic data

Do I need to somehow completely remove bitlocker before ubuntu will recognise the partition as NTFS?  any other hints and tips in this area?

Thanks

Further information: 15 October 2017
Thanks to the two responders already!
The partitions were created in Windows 10 pro prior to installing Ubuntu. 
I don't believe this is a problem with windows fast startup as it is not the partition with the windows OS, Hiberfil, etc on.  I also turned off fast startup and thst makes no difference  It's another partition with just files on it.  I have another machine that boots between Win 10 home (so no bitlocker) and Ubuntu 16.04.  On this one the windows c: drive partition exhibits exactly the behaviour mentioned in the second answer but my data only drive mounts just fine.  The data only partition is the only one I want to mount.

Gparted on my other machine recognises the partitions as ntfs, whereas on the machine with the problem they are shown as bitlocker in the filesystem column.

cheers

Comment: did you create the partition in windows or linux?

Comment: If encryption not enabled, it just may be Windows fast start up is still on. And Windows will keep turning it back on with updates.http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions and: http://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation so NTFS data partition is also left mounted or not readable from Linux if hibernation/fast start up is on.

Answer (score 0):

This problem was due to the partition in question being actually encrypted in Windows bitlocker, despite the fact that windows control panel indicated bitlocker was not enabled. from Windows 10 I used the PowerShell command Disable-Bitlocker on the partition.  This utility actually decrypts the drive and completely removes all trace of bitlocker from it so the next time I booted into Ubuntu I was able to mount the drive.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj649832(v=wps.630).aspx